# Problems with running app In flutter simulator after reinstalling Xcode

Tags: xcode, visual-studio, flutter

Sorry I need help I am total new into programming/developing.

Im working om a Mac M1 and I did experience problems.

In terminal I write:
flutter create and the flutter run.

The app builds.

But when I try to run and debug in vscode this error comes up:

```
Expected ios/Runner.xcodeproj but this file is missing. No application found for TargetPlatform.ios. Is your project missing an ios/Runner/Info.plist? Consider running "flutter create ." to create one.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: How are you creating the flutter apps? The error message tells you to use the command `flutter create`, are you using it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I did this:                               In terminal: flutter create and the flutter run. The app builds, but when I try to run and debug in vscode this error comes up:                              Expected ios/Runner.xcodeproj but this file is missing.
No application found for TargetPlatform.ios.
Is your project missing an ios/Runner/Info.plist?
Consider running "flutter create ." to create one.